# Parsec csv parser parsing extra line

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have defined the follwing Parsec parser for parsing csv files into a table of strings, i.e. `[[String]]`

```
--A csv parser is some rows seperated, and possibly ended, by a newline charater
csvParser = sepEndBy row (char '\n')
--A row is some cells seperated by a comma character
row = sepBy cell (char ',')
--A cell is either a quoted cell, or a normal cell
cell = qcell <|> ncell
--A normal cell is a series of charaters which are neither , or newline. It might also be an escape character
ncell = many (escChar <|> noneOf ",\n")
--A quoted cell is a " followd by some characters which either are escape charaters or normal characters except for "
qcell = do
    char '"'
    res <- many (escChar <|> noneOf "\"")
    char '"'
    return res
--An escape character is anything followed by a \. The \ will be discarded.
escChar = char '\\' >> anyChar
```

*I don't really know if the comments are too much and annoying, of if they are helping. As a Parsec noob they would help me, so I thought I would add them.*

It works pretty good, but there is a problem. It creates an extra, empty, row in the table. So if I for example have a csv file with 10 rows(*that is, only 10 lines. No empty lines in the end**), the `[[String]]` structure will have length 11 and the last list of `String`s will contain 1 element. An empty `String` (at least this is how it appears when printing it using `show`).

My main question is: Why does this extra row appear, and what can I do to stop it?

Another thing I have noted is that if there are empty lines after the data in the csv files, these will end up as rows containing only an empty `String` in the table. I thought that using `sepEndBy` instead of `sepBy` would make the extra empty lines by ignored. Is this not the case?

*After looking at the text file in a hex editor, it seems that it indeed actually ends in a newline character, even though vim doesn't show it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each row to have at least one cell, you can use `sepBy1` instead of `sepBy`. This should also stop empty rows being parsed as a row. The difference between `sepBy` and `sepBy1` is the same as the difference between `many` and `many1`: the `1` version only parses sequences of at least one element. So `row` becomes this:

```
row = sepBy1 cell (char ',')
```

Also, the usual style is to use `sepBy1` in infix: `` cell `sepBy1` char ',' ``. This reads more naturally: you have a "cell separated by a comma" rather than "separated by cell a comma".

EDIT: If you don't want to accept empty cells, you have to specify that `ncell` has at least one character using `many1`:

```
ncell = many1 (escChar <|> noneOf ",\n")
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I have not stated my problem entirely correct. It turns out that the extra row, and the empty line rows, in fact does not become empty lists when parsed. Instead they end up containing 1 element which appears to be an empty `String`. I will change my question the reflect this.

Your solution does, in any case, not work. Probably because I didn't properly state the problem. But I should use `sepBy1` anyways, so thank you for the help :)

Comment: @andvin The problem is that `many` and `sepBy` can succeed without consuming, and the terminating `sep` is optional with `sepEndBy`. When the final `'\n'` is reached, the parser tries to read a further row with the remaining input. `row` tries to parse the first cell. `ncell` succeeds with `""`, row looks for a `','`, finds none, succeeds with the one cell `[""]`. `rows` checks for a `'\n'`, finds none, and succeeds with the last row `[""]`. You must make both, `cell` and `row` fail on emty input to get rid of the last empty row (`[]` if you use `many1` in `ncell` but not `sepBy1` in row).

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem. However now i can't have empty cells, but I can see how distinguishing empty lines and rows with just one empty cell is impossible. But maybe distinguishing rows with one empty cell, and that last non-existent line is possible? Maybe if I used `sepBy` instead of `sepEndBy` ? I mean, it should be possible to tell the difference between an empty line and EOF right?

Anyways, I think i should look into how csv is normally defined, and if it even allows rows of different length.

Comment: @andvin: Does your input have anything (e.g. any whitespace) on the last line? Is there even a trailing newline after the last "real" CSV row?

Comment: There is in fact a newline after the last csv row, but i thought that there was not. It seems that vim adds it automatically, and then hides it.

So now I basically understand why my code does what it does. I will just have to figure out how to handle empty lines.